# Neural segmentation network gives different output based on test batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, output, vision

I have implemented and trained a neural segmentation model on (224, 224) images.
However, during testing, the model returns slightly different results based on the shape of the test batch.

The following images are results obtained during testing on my pre-trained model.

[image]

[image]

The first image is the prediction I get when I predict a single example (let's call it `img0`) (so the **input** is `[img0]` and has shape (1,224,224))

The second image is the prediction I get for the same image but when it's among a batch with 7 other images (so the **input** is `[img0, img1, ..., img7]` and has shape (8,224,224)).

The first output is closer than what I expected, compared to second output.

However, I don't understand why the outputs are different to begin with... Is this supposed to be normal behaviour?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the last few lines of the model.summary() output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was coming from the batch normalization layers that were in my model.
I use `training=true` during my calls to the model.

As a result, batch normalization normalizes the batches based on their norm, and that norm changes based on batch size.

Therefore, this is normal behavior!

Answer (score 0):

yes, the batch size is a hyperparameter, meaning you should do trial and error to find the best value for it (hyperparameter tunning). but you should also be aware of its effect on the training process. in each batch the loss would be calculated by feedforwarding the samples in the batch and then the backpropagation will be performed by using that loss value. so if you choose a small value for the batch size, it is very possible that you won't be able to find the global optima and you just fluctuate around it or even stuck in local optima (from an optimization point of view). A very small value for batch size (especially 1) is not very recommended.

also, you need a validation set (more than one sample) to become fully sure that whether your model is accurate or not.

Comment: I think the user is asking only for the test phase not for training.